# listen to backbone event from a require module

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone view WishListView.js like this..

```
define( [
    'jquery',
    'backbone', 
    'wishListInfo',       
    'bcomWishList/views/WishListFilterUtil'
],

function ( $, Backbone, WishListInfo, WishListFilterUtil ) {
var wishListView = Backbone.View.extend( {
filterUtil : WishListFilterUtil,
wishlistInfo: '',

initialize: function () {
    self.wishlistInfo = new WishListInfo( null, options );
    self.listenTo( self.wishlistInfo, 'sync', self.wishlistInfoListener );
    self.listenTo(self.filterUtil,  'getFilterData' ,self.render );
},
render:{

},
```

here WishListInfo is another backbone view class file so i am able to listen to an event 'sync', working well, but suppose i have an js file WishListFilterUtil and am loading as a dependency in this view,  an when am listen to an event am getting the error 
obj[implementation] is not a function
and here is my WishListFilterUtil.js file

```
define( [
    'jquery',
    'backbone',       
],
function ( $, Backbone) {

var data = {
        filterQuery:[],
        filterAccessController: true,
        guestListShareId: '',
        shareWishid: '',
    }
function handleFilterView(){
        if ( data.filterQuery.indexOf( "available" ) === -1 ) {
                self.trigger( 'getFilterData', x );
                        //here i have to call the render function of WishListView.js file
        } else {
                        self.initialize();
        }
 }
}
```

this is the error am getting obj[implementation] is not a function. Please help me in this.

Thank you..

Comment: try replacing self with this!

Comment: I tried this instead of self but getting the same error.

Comment: `WishListFilterUtil` is not mixed witg Backbone.Event and cannot be handled with `listenTo`. And I guess the `handleFilterView()` function haven't any `trigger` method inside it.

Comment: I included WishListFilterUtil as a dependency in WishListView like 
filterUtil : WishListFilterUtil, and am listening an event on this module, and the trigger is not working because this is not a backbone view,